# / readonly on boot, but don't see why. how to investigate and fix?

Tags: debian, boot

Root filesystem mounted fine under squeeze, and after I upgraded to
wheezy. I've been living with it for a bit, so I'm not exactly sure,
but I think it started after doing a dist-upgrade on wheezy, but that
could be coincidence. The machine is a Lenovo T400 FWIW.

boot screen photo[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svPNp.png) shows first warnings about read-only file system; nothing is logged obviously

fsck finds no problems[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CllFB.png)

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

above works fine

(but I have to restart network-manager and gdm3 to get a usable
system; I'm not sure it is related, but I can't seem to connect to a
service running on localhost, eg python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 and
in another terminal w3m times out sending request to localhost port 8080)

I don't notice anything amiss in fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2934c627-6f1a-438b-a877-1544108c7418 /               ext3 errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=39b1f59e-6193-4c46-8b4d-80b183f0b19c none            swap    sw           0       0
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
/dev/sdb1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Hopefully I'm doing something
obviously wrong and fixable, but if not any hints about how to debug?

...

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
```

outputs

```
tune2fs 1.42.2 (27-Mar-2012)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          2934c627-6f1a-438b-a877-1544108c7418
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              14893056
Block count:              59547904
Reserved block count:     2977395
Free blocks:              50391869
Free inodes:              14576981
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1009
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Filesystem created:       Tue May  3 01:44:56 2011
Last mount time:          Wed Apr 18 13:11:25 2012
Last write time:          Tue Apr 17 23:51:46 2012
Mount count:              5
Maximum mount count:      25
Last checked:             Tue Apr 17 23:51:46 2012
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
Next check after:         Sun Oct 14 23:51:46 2012
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       9145036
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      af8ca7f0-bcad-49f3-98c0-9b19a531a885
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

...

It appears that /etc/init.d/checkroot.sh isn't being run at boot, and that's the script that finally remounts root as rw (if I run it after boot, it does exactly that). I'm using Debian testing/wheezy. There are dependency annotations in /etc/init.d files, but beyond that I'm not sure how to tell more about the init system.

...

Fixed, but no idea how it happened or if the fix is exactly how the system ought be. I noticed checkfs and mtab in /etc/rcS.d, but no checkroot, so I added it:

```
cd /etc/rcS.d
ln -s ../init.d/checkroot.sh S06checkroot.sh
```

After rebooting twice (first time could have been my confusion, but I added some further instrumentation to checkroot.sh between them), I'm back up with rw on boot (and the problem with listening to/requesting from localhost disappeared, so I guess it was related).

(I see on a squeeze system I have access to it's at S07checkroot.sh; I was close perhaps.)

Comment: Did you try a fsck of the root filesystem? Boot from a liveCD, then do the fsck.

Comment: Yes. I did fsck in single user mode, screenshot linked from [2] above.

Comment: Try it from a liveCD, and try to mount the filesystem. Gheck `dmesg` for errors.

Answer (score 3):

There is an error on your /root filesystem and fstab remounts /root as read only.

The line in fstab

`UUID=2934c627-6f1a-438b-a877-1544108c7418 / ext3 errors=remount-ro 0 1`

is what is causing /root to mount read only.

From the `mount (8)` man page

```
errors={continue|remount-ro|panic}
Define the behaviour when an error is encountered.  (Either ignore errors
and just  mark  the  filesystem  erroneous and continue, or remount the
filesystem read-only, or panic and halt the system.)  The default is set in
the  filesystem superblock, and can be changed using tune2fs(8).
```

You should ultimately find out what is wrong with your /root filesystem. You can easily boot from a rescue disk and run an fsck on /root. If you choose to ignore the potential errors, just change the line in fstab to `errors=continue`.

Comment: changing remount-ro to continue doesn't change behavior upon reboot. I'll have to try another fsck from a rescue disk, thanks.

Comment: Check the superblock. `tune2fs -l /dev/sda1` and look for the entry `Errors behavior`. Is it set to `continue` or `read-only`?

Comment: Continue. Added full output to the question.

Comment: It feels like we are missing something obvious...try booting from a rescue/live cd and running the fsck on all the filesystems. That's definitely the next step.

Comment: fsck'd from a rescue usb and got the same, clean, output as from single user mode reflected in http://i.stack.imgur.com/CllFB.png (file and inode counts slightly different due to subsequent use).

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and it was caused by the wrong UUID for the root FS being set in /etc/fstab. I guess some upgrade auto-detected it and got it wrong.

Remount the / partition rw, using `blkid` to get the right UUID and replace in /etc/fstab fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your root filesystem isnt being mounted read/write because youre not telling it to.

```
UUID=2934c627-6f1a-438b-a877-1544108c7418 /               ext3 errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Your mount options are only `errors=remount-ro`, there's nothing about read/write in there. The standard practice is to have `defaults` in your mount options. `defaults` provides several other mount options, one of them is `rw`, thus providing read/write.

So you need to add either `defaults` or `rw` to the options field of your fstab.

**EDIT:**
From thinking about it a bit more (and from discussion in comments below), the `defaults` and `rw` options might not fix it. The reason being is that the remount behavior is entirely dependent upon the distro's init scripts. I've seen distros pull the mount settings from fstab on boot, but its also possible that the init script is completely ignoring fstab options when it goes to remount root (and uses some hard coded settings in the script).

Comment: I tried adding `rw` earlier today to no effect.  I'm not sure it should have one though, the system I'm typing on now only has `relatime,errors=remount-ro` as mount options, and mounts rw. I'll try `defaults` shortly though anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose this behavior is dependent upon your distribution's init scripts. Its entirely possible its completely ignoring whether fstab has `rw`/`defaults` specified or not. Try doing `grep remount /etc/init.d/*` and see if there's an init script doing something special.

Comment: In debian the system boots with a ro filesystem then changes to rw once it's determined that it's safe to do so. Though, I can't tell if his system is never switching to rw or switching back because of an error.

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious in /etc/init.d scripts, but I guess I see /etc/init.d/checkroot.sh is where root is potentially fsck'd and finally remounted in its final state. That gives me someplace to continue trying to figure this out, thanks Patrick and bahamat.

Comment: `defaults` is useless if you have other options, it's only a placeholder when you have no other option and you can't leave the field empty because there are other columns to the right. `rw` is the default; but `/` is not initially mounted by looking at `fstab`, so the boot scripts have to pick up the right options at some point and remount it.

Comment: Instrumented checkroot.sh, checkfs.sh, and mountall.fs with some log_warning_msg's and it seems the first isn't running at boot, latter two definitely are (but don't mount root). When I run checkroot.sh after booting, it runs fine.

Comment: @mlinksva If `checkroot.sh` doesn't run, that's definitely a problem, and explains why `/` isn't remounted read-write. Please edit that into your question, and tell us what init mechanism you're using (SysV? `file-rc`? Upstart? Systemd?).

Comment: Added to question. As said there, I'm using Debian wheezy. Dimly think that means SysV but need to investigate further.